# How to implement a function parameter that allows a list of properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a function that takes as a parameter an arbitrary list of object's properties.  Similar to how Entity Framework has implemented it.  In this example, it passes a list of columns to the Select method:

```
var ctx = new MyDbContext();
var foo = ctx.Cases.Select(c => new { c.Caption, c.ID_Case, c.ID_Type });
```

I understand that `Select` is done in the context of `IQueryable<TSource>` extension method.  I don't need it be that sophisticated - an ability to enter properties with intellisense will do.

Example of what I ideally would like:

```
class Cases {
  void DoStuff(/*parameter definition here*/) {
     // method body
  }
  public string Caption { get; set; }
  public int ID_Case { get; set; }
  public int ID_Type { get; set; }
}

var c = new Cases();
c.DoStuff(new { c.Caption, c.ID_Type });
```

P.S. I'd rather not use `nameof` and pass properties as strings.

Comment: I think you might be looking for the params keyword? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params